# What happened to the Book of Skulls movie?

Tags: robert-silverberg

In the mid-2000s, while browsing at a book store, I came across a reprint of Robert Silverberg's novel *The Book of Skulls*.  Having read the book about a decade earlier, it caught my eye that the new edition said that it would soon be a major motion picture.  However, that movie evidently never got made, and there seems to be very little information about it on the Web.  Since the book came up in again in a discussion today, I found myself wondering:  What happened to the film development?  Is there any reliable information about why it did not get made?

To some extent, it's not really a surprise that the touted movie didn't happen.  *The Book of Skulls* is not exactly typical Hollywood fare.  On the one hand, it has an enormous amount of sex in it, but no romantic angle, and very little violence.  Nor does it have the makings of a typical horror film.  Moreover, while the book does have a lot of interesting themes and ideas, it is very, very dated.  You don't have to read more than ten pages to know that it could not have been written at any time but the early 1970s.  Still, I'm curious whether there's specific information about why the project didn't happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Robert Silverberg commented on the movie in the Yahoo Group [The Worlds of Robert Silverberg](https://beta.groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/theworldsofrobertsilverberg/info) in 2007:

> There was a palace upheaval at Paramount and the president of the company went out. Her husband, William Friedkin, had been signed to direct SKULLS, but he left with her and I think the deal is dead. The usual Hollywood stuff. I got paid, at least.
>   <sub>August 21, 2007</sub>

and 2014:

> BOOK OF SKULLS was optioned by a whole slew of people from about 1976 on to 1993 or so, one after another as each option lapsed.  Then the last option-holder in the chain actually exercised the option, and the film was going to be made by Paramount, a director named and all (Wm Friedkin) and suddenly there was a management upheaval at Paramount and the project was killed.  So the book is still owned by the guy who picked up the option, and if he can't make a deal for it there will never be a movie.
>   <sub>March 18, 2014</sub>